# Plaid Integration With Xamarin forms

Tags: android, ios, forms, xamarin, plaid

As I am going to start a new Xamarin project, and I want to integrate Plaid client with that project. Customer needs to built that project with Xamarin forms(iOS and Android). Could you please send me some tutorial or document that can refer for integrating Plaid in Xamarin Forms(iOS and Android).

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin

Comment: Hi , I got the answer.

Comment: If you have fixed this issue,please post your solution to answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: I have added the answer.

Comment: for iOS version 13.5 or after, you need additional mtouch arguments to prevent the "ITMS-90809" error. https://github.com/ijeong1787fp/Plaid-Link-XamarinForms

Answer (score 1):

We need to change the info.plist and assemblyInfo.cs class in iOS project.

For iOS, you need to add the NSAllowsArbitaryLoads key to YES in NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your info.plist file.

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>
```

@ UIWebview is deprecated from iOS 13. So, you need to use wkwebview instead of webview. add the following code to the AssemblyInfo.cs file in the iOS platform project for the application

```
// Opt-in to using WkWebView instead of UIWebView.
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.WkWebViewRenderer))]
```

And in your page /UI add web view and name it as 'webView'. And in the code behind, add the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using Foundation;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace PlaidLinkXamarinForms
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var publickey = "YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY";
            var env = "Sandbox"; //development, production
        var product = "auth"; //transactions, auth, identity, income, assets, investments, liabilities
            var clientName = "PlaidLinkXamarinForms"

            var url = "https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link.html?isWebview=true&key=" + publickey + "&env=" + env + "&product=" + product + "&selectAccount=true&clientName=" + clientName + "&isMobile=true";

            webView.Source = url;

            webView.Navigating += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Url.ToLower().Contains("plaidlink:"))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Cancel = false;
                }
                var linkScheme = "plaidlink";
                var scheme = new Uri(e.Url);
                var param = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(e.Url);

                var actionScheme = scheme.Scheme;
                var actionType = scheme.Host;

                if(actionScheme == linkScheme)
                {
                    switch (actionType)
                    {
                        case "connected":
                            Debug.WriteLine("Successfully Connected");
                            break;
                        case "exit":
                Debug.WriteLine("Exit");
                            break;
                        case "event":
                            Debug.WriteLine($"Event name: {param["event_name"]}");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Debug.WriteLine($"Link action detected: {actionType}");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Before doing this, you should configure your account on Plaid website. There you will get some keys that you have to add to the above code.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, Please mark your reply as answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Looks like you lifted some code from this GitHub repository. You should credit and link to the code that you copy and pasted. https://github.com/ijeong1/Plaid-Link-XamarinForms